# incoming serial data interfering with MATLAB callbacks

Tags: user-interface, serial-port, matlab

I have a code that utilizes information taken over serial, compares it to a stored string, and then changes the color values of a panel in a GUI. this is done for 2 different panels. once the strcmp for both panels is 1, a button is enabled to close the GUI. i want to use a simple closereq() function to close it, but that wasn't working. to try something different, I commented out the closereq() and added in a disp('Success'). When pressing the button, Success will appear in the command window, but only after I manually pause the program from the editor panel.

this is my code:

```matlab
function varargout = WorkingGUI3(varargin)
% WORKINGGUI3 MATLAB code for WorkingGUI3.fig
%      WORKINGGUI3, by itself, creates a new WORKINGGUI3 or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = WORKINGGUI3 returns the handle to a new WORKINGGUI3 or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      WORKINGGUI3('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in WORKINGGUI3.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      WORKINGGUI3('Property','Value',...) creates a new WORKINGGUI3 or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before WorkingGUI3_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to WorkingGUI3_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help WorkingGUI3

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 02-Oct-2019 14:53:57

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
    'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
    'gui_OpeningFcn', @WorkingGUI3_OpeningFcn, ...
    'gui_OutputFcn',  @WorkingGUI3_OutputFcn, ...
    'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
    'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before WorkingGUI3 is made visible.
function WorkingGUI3_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to WorkingGUI3 (see VARARGIN)
handles.uipanels = [handles.uipanel1, handles.uipanel2];
set(handles.pushbutton5, 'enable', 'off');
% Choose default command line output for WorkingGUI3
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes WorkingGUI3 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = WorkingGUI3_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
delete(instrfind('Port', 'COM3'));
tag = serial('COM3');
fopen(tag);
BOX = char(zeros(2,14)); % matrix to be populated with incoming serial data
TrueValueData = 'C:\RfidChipTrueValues.xlsx';
[~,~,TrueValMat] = xlsread(TrueValueData);
% Creates matrix filled with the correct values
% indexed by box, which is the first row
% all proceeding rows are the master value
for i=1:inf
    for n = 1:2
        if i>10
            readData = fscanf(tag);
            if length(readData)>12
                BOX(str2double(readData(8)),1:14)= readData(11:24);
                if strcmp(TrueValMat{2,n}, BOX(n,:))
                    set(handles.uipanels(n), 'BackgroundColor', 'g');
                else
                    set(handles.uipanels(n), 'BackgroundColor', 'r');
                end
                drawnow
                if strcmp(TrueValMat{2,1}, BOX(1,:))...
                        && strcmp(TrueValMat{2,2}, BOX(2,:)) == 1
                    set(handles.pushbutton5, 'enable', 'on');
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton5.
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%closereq();
disp('It Works')
```

the final section

```matlab
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton5.
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%closereq();
disp('Success')
```

holds the callback to the button. I know its it correctly connected to the .fig because pressing the button makes Success appear, but only after manually pausing the program.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a short pause in the outer loop. For example: line below `for i=1:inf`, insert: `pause(0.01)`

Comment: works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @Rotem showed, adding a pause after the first for loop successfully allowed the program to close.